# Overriding a variable in two bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash

I have to bash scripts:

script1.sh

```
HELLO=hello
export HELLO
./script2.sh
echo $HELLO
```

script2.sh

```
echo $HELLO
HELLO=world
export $HELLO
```

The output is `hello hello` instead of `hello world`. How can I modify variables between scripts which call each other?

EDIT: Passing variables as arguments won't work. I don't know the number of variables which might be changed in script2.sh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to run the second script as a child process, you have to source it:

```
HELLO=hello
export HELLO
. ./script2.sh  # Note the dot at the beginning
echo $HELLO
```

No export is needed in the second script - you already told bash to export the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Exported variables are available in subshells (as is the case with `script2.sh` vs `script1.sh`), but not to parent shells.

For this reason, the variable set by `script1.sh` is available in `script2.sh`, but setting it in `script2.sh` will not make it available in `script1.sh` when `script2.sh` returns.

If you will to pass the variable back to the caller, you'd need to `echo` it, and grab the output of `script2.sh`. But then, you'll need `script2.sh` to write to stderr if you want to see its output:

script1.sh:

```
HELLO=hello
export HELLO
HELLO=$(./script2.sh)
echo >&2 $HELLO
```

script2.sh:

```
echo $HELLO >&2
HELLO=world
echo $HELLO
```

Answer (score 1):

When u call new script by ./script2.sh it forks new shell and new shell will be closed when script2 completes execution. When control comes back to script its still old shell so variable exported in script2 wont be available. To run script2 in same shell u have run it like ". ./script2.sh"

```
HELLO=hello
export HELLO
. ./script2.sh
echo $HELLO
```

Answer (score 0):

The environment of `script1.sh` contains `HELLO=hello`. Nothing you do in the child `script2.sh` will change that.